# What step am I messing up with this Sherman-Morrison formula

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, solution-verification

So I am given the matrices:

$$A = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 1 & -1 \\ 1 & 0 & 2 \\\end{pmatrix}\qquad A^{-1}=  \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 1 & -1 \\ 1 & 0 & 2 \\\end{pmatrix} \qquad C = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 1 & -1 \\ 1 & 2 & 2 \\\end{pmatrix} $$

I am then asked to use the Sherman-Morrison formula to find $C^{-1}$ so far I have:

$$u = \begin{pmatrix} 0 \\ 0 \\ 2 \\\end{pmatrix}\qquad v =  \begin{pmatrix} 0 \\ 1 \\ 1 \end{pmatrix} $$

$$A^{-1}uv^{\top} =  \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 1 & -1 \\ 1 & 0 & 2 \\\end{pmatrix} \cdot \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 2 & 2 \\\end{pmatrix}  =  \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 2 & 2 \\ 0 & -2 & -2 \\ 0 & 4 & 4 \\\end{pmatrix} $$

$$A^{-1}uv^{\top}A^{-1} =  \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 2 & 2 \\ 0 & -2 & -2 \\ 0 & 4 & 4 \\\end{pmatrix} \cdot  \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 1 & -1 \\ 1 & 0 & 2 \\\end{pmatrix}  =  \begin{pmatrix} 2 & 2 & 2 \\ -2 & -2 & -2 \\ 4 & 4 & 4 \\\end{pmatrix} $$

$$v^{\top}A^{-1} = \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1 & 1 \\ \end{pmatrix} \cdot\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 1 & -1 \\ 1 & 0 & 2 \\\end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 1 & 1 \\\end{pmatrix} $$

$$v^{\top}A^{-1}u = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 1 & 1 \\\end{pmatrix} \cdot\begin{pmatrix} 0 \\ 0 \\ 2\\\end{pmatrix} = 2$$

$$1+ v^{\top}A^{-1}u = 1 + 2 = 3$$

$$\dfrac{A^{-1}uv^TA^{-1}}{1+v^TA^{-1}u} =  \begin{pmatrix} 2 & 2 & 2 \\ -2 & -2 & -2 \\ 4 & 4 & 4 \\\end{pmatrix}  \cdot \frac13 =  \begin{pmatrix} 2/3 & 2/3 & 2/3 \\ -2/3 & -2/3 & -2/3 \\ 4/3 & 4/3 & 4/3 \\\end{pmatrix} $$

Which finally gives me $A^{-1} - \dfrac{A^{-1}uv^{\top}A^{-1}}{1+v^TA^{-1}u}$ which is $ \begin{pmatrix} 1/3 & -2/3 & 1/3 \\ 2/3 & 5/3 & -1/3 \\ -1/3 & -4/3 & 2/3 \\\end{pmatrix} $

but when I try to find $C^{-1}$ using other methods it comes out to be $$
\begin{bmatrix}
0 & -2 & 1 \\
1 & 3 & -1 \\
-1 & -4 & 2 \\
\end{bmatrix}
$$

So where did I go wrong?

Comment: The values of $A^{-1}$ and $v$ are wrong.